# What is the simplest way to secure an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API using Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am building a Web API using ASP.NET Core 2.1, i want this secured using Azure AD B2C. What is the simplest approach to this?

The Web API will contain endpoints such as GetMyTasks, GetMyAppointments etc.

After development of the Web API is complete, I will be building an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC web application and also a Xamarin application that will communicate with the Web API.

The way i envisage this working is that users will log into the web application or Xamarin app using B2C and calls to the Web API will include information about the user making the request and automatically know that the user is authenticated.

Any reference articles would be helpful.

Comment: Basically there should be a login process that does all of the authentication against AD, and when it authenticates successfully, issue a JWT token.  From there all the other methods only care about validating the JWT token which is simple as validating the signature, so they don't really need to be concerned with AD.  Is that what you're asking, or do you need help implementing the authentication with AD?

Comment: Thanks. does the code in this provide a good starting point to the approach: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/

Comment: If i take this approach then can my web app and xamarin app call the web api if they are authenticated using b2c?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with asp.net core 2.0. The same will work for 2.1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/